# (Excel) Trying to autofill a mid function that references a different sheet with each cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have data on 77 sheets and need to create on last sheet that pulls data from each sheet.  I'm using a mid formula because the data I need is in the middle of a string in a cell (A1 of every sheet).  Does anyone know of a quick way to autofill down this 78th sheet so that each cell (A1-A77) will pull from a different sheet?  I know I can pull down the mid function and then go back and change the sheet of each.  But that's going to take almost as much time as it would to manually copy and paste from each sheet.  If at all possible I'd like to do this with a formula and not VBA, as I am not very confident in my VBA skills.

The formula I am using is:

`=MID('16'!A$1,143,4)`

('16' Being the first sheet)

The next cell should be:

`=MID('17'!A$1,143,4)`

and so on, down to

`=MID('93'!A$1,143,4)`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the indirect function to convert text to range / sheet reference

```
=MID(INDIRECT("'" & row()+15 & "'!A$1"),143,4)
```